# Positioning images with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: icons in position in the chamber]

[image: empty chamber]

[image: icon1]

[image: icon2]

[image: icon3]

I am attempting to position the attached icons into the background image of an ammo chamber using HTML and CSS. What I've managed to do is achieve the desired effect by positioning each icon absolutely with top and left attributes as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        img {
            position: absolute;
        }

        #facebook {
            left: 103px;
            top: 28px;
        }

        #twitter {
            left: 37px;
            top: 142px;
        }

        #rss {
            left: 168px;
            top: 142px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="chamber" src="chamber.png">
    <img id="facebook" src="facebook.png">
    <img id="twitter" src="twitter.png">
    <img id="rss" src="rss.png">
</body>
```

Is this the proper way to position elements in such a manner? Will it cause side effects depending on the resolution of the screen/browser? Thank you for the help.

Comment: provide a jsfiddle if it's possible

Comment: Depends on what you actually want

Comment: Using fixed pixel values will mean that the item will not be responsive, but in general, your question is too broad and answers will be opinion based...so it's off-topic for SO.

Comment: If you want it to position  dynamically to that spot ??? things get complicated

Comment: you should make a div that wrapps your images, in there is your chamber image wich should not be positioned absolute, it shoiuld have position relative. The the other images should be positioned absolute.

Comment: You could merge the images, this way you are sure they are never seperated (even with disabled js and or css), links can still work with an old fashion imagemap

Comment: @Paulie_D Claiming the question is off topic for SO isn't very constructive when 4 people quickly answered my question with valuable input.

Comment: Fact is...it IS off-topic according to the SO guidelines. The fact that it has answers doesn't change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap those images in a div and apply relative position to that div and work with absolute position with images:

```
<div class="circle">
    <img id="chamber" src="chamber.png">
    <img id="facebook" src="facebook.png">
    <img id="twitter" src="twitter.png">
    <img id="rss" src="rss.png">
</div>

.circle{
  position: relative;
  background: url(circle-image.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 400px; /*layout as yours*/
  height: 400px; /*layout as yours*/
}
#chamber{ /* do for all other images*/
  position: absolute; /* now it is positioned in relation with circle div*/
  top: 30px; /*layout as yours*/
  left: 30px; /*layout as yours*/
}
```

Use firebug or any developer tool to position the element.

Answer (score 3):

```
<body>
    <div id="ammo">
        <img id="chamber" src="chamber.png">
        <img id="facebook" src="facebook.png">
        <img id="twitter" src="twitter.png">
        <img id="rss" src="rss.png">
    </div>
</body>
```

---

```
    #ammo {
        position: relative;
        width: <widthofammo>;
        height:<heightofammo>;
    }
    img {
        position: absolute;
    }

    #chamber {
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    #facebook {
        left: 103px;
        top: 28px;
    }

    #twitter {
        left: 37px;
        top: 142px;
    }

    #rss {
        left: 168px;
        top: 142px;
    }
```

---

Its good to wrap in a relative positioned element so that it will not break when you add more elements to `body`.

Absolute positioned elements are positioned relative to the nearest `positioned` parent. `positioned` can be any positioning other than default `static` positioning(ie.fixed/absolute/relative). Or if no elements are found, it will be positioned relative to `body`.

Now in your code `absolute` elements will be positioned relative to `body`. If you add some more code, like a `h1` before images, things will overlap. If you use a relative positioned element to wrap all the `img` , even if you add more elements like `h1` at beginning, it will follow static/sequential ordering and avoids overlapping elements.

Take time to read this article : http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use `background-position` property in your sample

Or,another solution would be CSS Sprites.

HTML:

```
<div class="main-wrapper ">
    <div class="inside-img-facebook "></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-wrapper {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 94px 20px;   
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMzvX.png');
}
.inside-img-facebook {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px center;
    background:  url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN3hc.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Take a look how it could be done  [Fiddle is here!](http://jsfiddle.net/hqtt93kc/)

it will definitely help you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can wrap the 3 icons in a div with the background of chamber.png. And make them position:relative

```
<style>
.chamber{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    background-img:url("chamber.png");
}
#facebook,#twitter,#rss{
    /*
    relative does not work here
    position:relative;
    */
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
#facebook {
    left: 103px;
    top: 28px;
}
//position for the icons...
</style>
<div class="chamber">
    <img id="facebook" src="facebook.png">
    <img id="twitter" src="twitter.png">
    <img id="rss" src="rss.png">

</div>
```

Then no matter how the screen resolution changes, the chamber will be the same size and the icons will be in the same place relative to the chamber.

Comment: I'd put the icons in div background if I do it myself. But please specify a bit more why it's not good to have relative position on imgs? @Pinki

Comment: Because if you want to add one more ore remove another, every image gets moved, since they're relative and not absolute.

Comment: Ahh I see... Relative positioned blocks still occupy their original space, seems like that's the problem

Comment: Yes indeed, therefore position absolute is better